# Nested weights programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, custom-controls, custom-component

I'm creating a custom control which extends a LinearLayout. Im placing some textView's, inner Layouts inside this custom widget. And Im using addView() API for this purpose and have to use nested weights inside.

Is this affects performance badly as in the case of nested wieght sin Android XML Layouts?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing.  Whether you do it in the program or in the XML, you are causing the system to measure things multiple times.